# MySQL database performance select on large/huge table

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, large-data, database

I'm using a MySQL database and have to perform some select queries on large/huge tables (e.g. 267,736 rows and 30 columns).

Query details:

- Only select queries (the data in the table is fixed, never an update, insert or delete)
- Select query on all the columns (business requirement)
- Mostly limit the number of rows (LIMIT 10 to all rows -> user can choose)
- Could be ordered by one or multiple columns (creation of indexes here will not help since the user can order by any column he likes)
- Could be filtered by a value the user chooses (where filter on one or more columns)

Currently the queries take up to 2 seconds, which is to long.
Is there a way to speed them up?

- Which storage engine should I use: InnoDB/MyISAM/...
- Should I have a primary key, even if I will never use him?
- ...?

Comment: It's a question for dba.stackexcange. For select on large table, sybase IQ is optimized. And MyISAM is faster on select than InnoDB.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE `%buffer%`.  How much RAM do you have?  How big (GB) is the table?  (I am fishing for whether the table can stay cached.)

Answer (score 0):

You should (must actually) use indexes.

Create indexes on all columns with which `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` is going to be used. Also study and use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html) to see the impact of the indexes and to optimize your queries.

You don't have to create a primary key if there is no column with unique data in your table, but it is very likely that you do have such a column (id, time...). In this case you should use primary key to filter your queries.

Number of columns in the query has close to no impact on `SELECT` speed.

As long as you make "Only select queries" storage engine does not matter either. `MyISAM` might be a bit faster, but `InnoDB` has many features you will need when you decide that your "Only select queries" rule must be broken.

Comment: I explained in my question that ordering or filtering can be done on all the columns. So indexes will not help me with this case. There is no standard unique column available (of course I can always create one via auto-increment in MySQL). The "rule" of only select queries will not be broken, so I think I will go for the MyISAM storage engine.

Comment: This means you have to add indexes on all columns. Indexes are made exactly for your case. You might also look into normalizing and/or partitioning your data. It is hard to say anything more specific without looking at your data.

Comment: you must create 1 composite index where all fields included that you are using in the where in the order which reduce the result most at first an so on

Comment: One composite index is not going to be used if the order of filtered columns is different from the specified in the index. It is not going to be used for ordering either, unless the table is ordered by the first column in the index. And I really don't think it is absolutely necessary to search and order by ALL columns. This is bad choice architecturally. This is the real problem in this case.